# How can I install MS Office 2013 on my ubuntu 16.04 laptop?

Tags: microsoft-office

I am trying to install MS Office 2013 on my ubuntu 16.04 laptop. I have been searching all over the web and haven't found anything useful. Please help!

Comment: Use a program called PlayOnLinux https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-3-0.html

Comment: You might want to consider LibreOffice, which is a very capable office suite.

Comment: If you must have Office 2013 for office or school "total compatibility" you might consider installing Windows as a second OS on this laptop. Other wise use LibreOffice and save documents in MS Office format choosing one of the older MS Office versions.

Comment: Libreoffice can not completely replace MS Office. I have done analysis reports on excel and despite being a huge advocate of open source software, I can not recommend LIbreoffice for 'serious' users.

Comment: @AnuragPriyadarshi  That may be true, but you should most certainly stop using Excel for analysis of any kind.   It's a question of 'when', not 'if' , that either Excel bugs or collapses in formula propagation will make your output incorrect.

Comment: @Carl . our comments are off-topic. The OP doesn't ask for a comparison. I was responding to an earlier comment which proposed considering LibreOffice.

Answer (score 6):

WPS Office looks just like MS Office. And it works fine in Ubuntu.

Get the deb package from here: http://wps-community.org/. Then open a Terminal window and type: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. After gdebi is installed, close the Terminal, right-click on wps office deb file and choose open with gdebi. Wait for the installation to finish and that's it. And yes, it is free for linux, despite of what some 'wiseshots' may think.

Comment: Can you please explain how to install WPS office?

Comment: Use the [edit] button to add this into your answer to make it easier to find, please. You have a good answer, but it's in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to what answers here say, you cannot get anything above Office 2010 to run. (Information from personal experience and research a few months ago, so something may have changed.)

It just requires too much for WINE (PlayOnLinux is just a wrapper for WINE) to handle, and will crash before launch.

Like others have suggested, you can use Office Online, but that doesn't work if you use an offline key. Your only options in this are either using 2010 or trying out Open Office or Libre Office.

Comment: According to one user, Word and Excel 2013 are working fine in playonlinux, but "rendering of windows, right screen size and minimize, maximize is crap, slow response of UI in general" are issues. But they posted an update that supposedly fixes many of them. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3ukrfh/microsoft_office_2013_on_linux_using_playonlinux/

Comment: @Zacharee1 a more complicated but realistic option is to install Windows as a second OS

Comment: @NickWeinberg how come I never found that? Would've been _really_ handy.

Comment: This is not true. You can install Microsoft Office 2010 on Ubuntu using PlayOnLinux. But only the 32-bits version of MS Office works.

Comment: @rpmcruz I said anything above 2010.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I read you too fast, sorry. I stand corrected. Though many people have recently reported MS Office 2013 to work, but it's troublesome (I managed to install it after a lot of pain, but could not overcome the black window while running).

Answer (score 1):

**You can't. MS Office only runs on Windows (and Mac OS).**

You could *try* running it on WINE, but no guarantees.

WINE stands for **W**ine **I**s **N**ot an **E**mulator
It is a compatibility layer that allows running Win32 apps on Linux.

However, it is **FAR** from perfect. Many applications will will simply crash during install or on launch.

---

You can install wine with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then you can try installing office by double-clicking the setup EXE.

It will probably crash during install.

---

## An alternative is [Office Online.](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx)

Comment: @NickWeinberg - From the page it looks buggy.